# Why doesn't appending comma in the end of an array doesn't give any error?

Tags: java

```
class TestClass {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String[] str = {"amnsi", "haris",};
        //------------------------------^
        for (String s : str) {
            System.out.println(s + " " + str.length);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case why didn't i get any error after ,

Comment: Because it's valid Java syntax, basically... from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6: "A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and is ignored."

Comment: why is it so.. if i place that comma in the starting of the array then get the compile time exception

Comment: Basically "because it's useful". It's really, really handy when generating code, for example...

Comment: Because the language specification says so.

Comment: And because you may do cut&copy&paste&whatever without worrying that the last element needs a special treatment.

Comment: haha appreciate that @JonSkeet